# Determining land cover change over time

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, land-cover

I am new to GIS and still learning. It’s interesting but becoming too complicated for me. A part of my project is to determine the land cover change in some counties in Texas from 2001 to 2011. 
So, a friend told me to use this approach using ArcGIS 10.3:

- I downloaded the Texas NLCD data
- I opened ArcMap, used the county shapefile to select the counties I’m interested in, I then overlaid the Texas land cover data (started with the 2006 data; just to try it out) on it.
- After selecting the counties, I created a specific buffer zone around them.
- Using ArcMap tools, I clicked spatial analyst tools →extraction→extract by mask→ it gave the option to select what land cover data I want in the input raster, I chose the Texas land cover data →then I selected the land cover data of my counties of interest into the input raster/feature mask, then selected an output file and ran  it. The result was a number of legends with different colors indicating different land cover types. I am interested in specific land cover types (four actually). What can I do to get only the legends of the land cover types I am interested in?
- I also went further to click on the patch grid menu→then the spatial analyst (Fragstat interface), after which I chose the layer I wanted to use (land cover data of the counties of choice), clicked analysis by class and chose only class area under the class options menu, then I clicked run. I got an error saying Fragstat unable to run, and a table with no data output.

Is there anything I should have done? Am I using the right approach for this analysis?

Answer (score 2):

This question actually deserves a much more complicated answer since LCLUC (Land Cover Land Use Change) is a specific discipline in geography that many people dedicate their life to researching.

To briefly contribute an answer, I will state that it sounds like you did an *unsupervised classification*. The variations in land cover that the tool spit out show differences in the pixels across the raster data you input. These differences can be determined in **many ways** but the tool you used uses one spatial analysis algorithm. You should look at the colors and what they represent, discover a pattern, determine what each land cover type is represented by which colors. Then be prepared to justify your reasoning.

As for the error - is there more information? Usually they have a description or a error code.

If you would like to learn more about LCLUC and the various tools that can be used to conduct this research, I recommend doing some good googling. For instance, I found [this blog by esri](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/05/13/using-landsat-services-to-study-land-cover-change-over-time/).

I personally use a robust remote sensing software for LCLUC analysis - ENVI. They have excellent documentation on the various supervised and unsupervised classification methods available and what logic the software uses to determine its output.